# flutter splash screen navigation bar color has a problem

Tags: android, flutter

i use flutter native splash screen package and after setting it to fullscreen and adding some native code like :
@android:color/transparent
in styles.xml , bottom navigation bar color becomes transparent for the first time when i run the app.
but after that , it shows a black/transparent gradiant.
[navigation bar has a black/transparent gradiant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdRVa.jpg)

setting flutter splash screen navigation bar color to transparent

Answer (score 0):

You can set code in `MainActivity` class native for android :

```
import android.os.Build // add this line
import android.os.Bundle // add this line

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
            window.navigationBarColor = 0 

        }
    }
}
```

Or

Inside in `main()` set this code :

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  );
```